# Drivers for 2.3.3 device to work as MTP

Tags: samsung, usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-y, mtp

I have a samsung Galaxy y device running 2.3.3 , where can i find the drivers of this device , to connect as MTP.

checked in the website of device manufacturers.
tried installing drivers from device manager also

Comment: Have you installed Samsung Kies? That has the USB drivers bundled with it. Here is your device page, contains like to Kies: http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/android/GT-S5360MAAXEU-support

Answer (score -2):

For those of us who are frustrated in trying to alter the file system to MTP and cannot find how to change it. Do not despair.

If you've opened Samsung Keis and connected phone with a USB cable and got the error message, go to your phone and swipe top to bottom on the NOTIFICATIONS list you will see the USB symbol on the left hand side and the line stating - Connected as Camera. If it says - Connected Media Device - then your connected properly. To Change from Connected as Camera, tap/select the line - Connected as Camera and you will be shown another screen with the Camera option selected - Just select Media Device MTP and you will be able to connect to Samsung Keis, and all will be calm and peacful, no more screaming at the PC or mobile phone.

Comment: So, that's five answers from you, all copy-paste versions of the other. What makes you think that's a good idea?